# MatAutocomplete or MdAutocomplete: input inside

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to give user an option to type different search terms inside the input that is located inside angular material 2 `MdAutocomplete` (or `MatAutocomplete`) `md-option`.

Current code:

```
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option disabled>
    <md-icon>search</md-icon>
    {{'WELCOME_WIZARD.SEARCH_FOR_A_DEV_TEAM' | translate}}
  </md-option>
  <md-option (click)="auto.showPanel">
    <span>
      <md-form-field class="p-input-full-width p-select-adjusted">
        <input mdInput
               name="searchTerm" ngModel
               [formControl]="searchTeamCtrl"
               placeholder="{{'WELCOME_WIZARD.SEARCH_START_TYPING' | translate}}"
               aria-label="state">
      </md-form-field>
    </span>
  </md-option>
  <md-option *ngFor="let team of foundTeams | async" [value]="team.name">
    <span>{{ team.name }}</span>
  </md-option>
  <md-option disabled>
    <md-icon>star</md-icon>
    {{'WELCOME_WIZARD.FAVORITES' | translate}}
  </md-option>
  <md-option *ngFor="let team of filteredTeams | async" [value]="team.name">
    <span>{{ team.name }}</span>
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The problem is that when the user clicks on the option with input, the autocomplete closes. I've been able to bypass this by giving the `md-option` a parameter of `disabled`, but another problem arises: the input doesn't react to space key anymore.

Has anybody managed to successfully integrate something similar, or maybe there is a solution to the space key?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your use case is, but `md-option` was definitely not designed for this behavior. What is happening is that the (click) event inside an option tries to [select it](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/0ea43700efb105aa02ad3b1d3f800bf4a9925883/src/lib/core/option/option.ts#L71). A (keydown) event of SPACE also tries to [select it](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/0ea43700efb105aa02ad3b1d3f800bf4a9925883/src/lib/core/option/option.ts#L186-L194), but since it is disabled, nothing happens and then `preventDefault()` is called.

Comment: @WillHowell what you are saying is correct. I was searching for a way to override it and it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `stopPropagation()` on the click event that focuses the input.

```
<mat-option>
  <input (click)="handleInputFocusClick($event)">=
</mat-option>

// ...

handleInputFocusClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

You can use a similar strategy if you deflect other events from propagating to the event handlers in `mat-option`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-jayo17?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks Will! Even though we decided to move away from the implementation with the input inside `mat-option` this solution is useful for the future.